# How to sum up the monthly salaries calculated within a loop into an annual salary in java

Tags: java, for-loop, io, sum

I have adopted the for loop, to calculate the salary of each month based on two factors: a fixed salary of $50000 and an additional $550/hr on extra hours worked in a month. The latter variable evidently varies per month, and so I adopted the scanner class to receive the input of each month. (All required parameters prior to my loop have been adequately defined)
My loop looks something like this:

```
    for(int month = 1; month <= 12; month++){

        System.out.print("How many extra hours did you work this month?");
        double extraHoursPerMonth = scan.nextInt();

        double bonusSalary = extraHoursPerMonth*bonusSalaryPerHour;
        double totalMonthlySalary = basicSalary + bonusSalary;

        System.out.println("Your salary for this month is $" + totalMonthlySalary);
```

When run, the total salary for each month is calculated successfully. How then do I proceed to find the annual salary?

I can not find any code I can use, to sum up, the monthly salaries previously calculated into a final sum and I feel like I'm up against a brick wall. I would appreciate any pointer, hints or advice on how to move forward.

Comment: Declare `double annualSalary = 0;` before the loop, and add `annualSalary += totalMonthlySalary;` after calculating `totalMonthlySalary`

Comment: "*I can not find any code I can use*" - You normally cannot find ready-to-use code to solve your problems. I would use a second (outer) loop to loop over each month, executin the existing (inner) loop and sum all values up in a new variable. You cannot use a final variable since you need to modify its value (well you could, but this is more of a hassle than it provides benefits).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a variable outside your for loop and add up the monthly salary for every iteration e.g.

```
int annualSalary = 0;
  for(int month = 1; month <= 12; month++){

    System.out.print("How many extra hours did you work this month?");
    double extraHoursPerMonth = scan.nextInt();

    double bonusSalary = extraHoursPerMonth*bonusSalaryPerHour;
    double totalMonthlySalary = basicSalary + bonusSalary;

    System.out.println("Your salary for this month is $" + 
    totalMonthlySalary);
  }
  System.out.println("Your annul salary for this year is $" + annualSalary);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the annual salary you can get it by multiplying the monthly salary by 12.

```
double anualSalary = basicSalary*12;
```

If you want the overall salary you should declare a variable after the declaration of *anualSalary* and before the for loop.

```
double overalSalary = anualSalary;
```

And then add the bonus salary in each loop of the for cycle.

```
...
overalSalary += bonusSalay;
...
```